# Finding the area of the triangle with vertices at $(ct, c/t)$, $(-ct, -c/t)$, $(ct^{2}, 2ct)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Question 8, part (iv) asks me to:

> **8.** Find the area of each of the triangles whose vertices are as given below:
>
> (iv) $(ct, c/t)$, $(-ct, -c/t)$, $(ct^{2}, 2ct)$.

So far (i.e. in parts (i), (ii) and (iii)), I've been using the method which question 7 in the book walks you through namely this:

1. First, draw the triangle. In this case, it's a little tricky, since you have no actual values, but it doesn't matter. For the purposes of my sketch, I plucked values out of thin air - $c = 2$, $t = 3$. I was a little worried about doing this, but a quick experiment with Wolfram|Alpha seems to suggest that this is a reasonable approach, since various other values of $c$ and $t$ (including $c > t$) give very much the same shape - something that looks a little like this:

[image]

2. Calculate the gradient of the line $BC = m_{BC}$

$m_{BC} = \dfrac{-c/t - 2ct}{-ct - ct^{2}} = \dfrac{1 + 2t^{2}}{t^{2}(1 + t)}$

Already this looks like it could do with simplifying, but neither I nor Wolfram|Alpha have managed it, so I moved on to step 3:

3. Find the equation of the line $BC = l_{BC}$

$y + \dfrac{c}{t} = \left(\dfrac{1 + 2t^{2}}{t^{2}(1 + t)}\right)(x + ct)$

After some algebra, I found that:

$y = \dfrac{(1 + 2t^{2})x}{t^{2}(1 + t)} + \dfrac{c(2t - 1)}{1 + t}$

4. Construct the perpendicular from $A$ to $BC$. Let this be denoted $l_{p}$.
5. Find the gradient of $l_{p} = m_{p}$

$m_{p} \cdot m_{BC} = -1$

$m_{p} = \dfrac{-t^{2}(1 + t)}{1 + 2t^{2}}$

6. Hence find the equation of $l_{p}$:

$y - ct = \left(\dfrac{-t^{2}(1 + t)}{1 + 2t^{2}}\right)(x - c/t)$

Eventually, I obtained:

$y = \dfrac{-t^{2}(1 + t)x + ct(2t^{2} + t + 2)}{1 + 2t^{2}}$

The idea is to then use simultaneous equations to find the coordinates of the point of intersection of the line $BC$ and $l_{p}$. These will be the coordinates of the foot of the perpendicular, of course. Let this point be $P$. You can then find the length of $BC$ (the base) and the length of $AP$ (the height) and use $A = \frac{1}{2}(bh)$.

It was at the point where, after eliminating $y$, I had:

$-(t^{2}(1 + t))^{2}x + ct(t^{2}(1 + t))(2t^{2} + t + 2) = (1 + 2t^{2})^{2}x + \dfrac{c(2t - 1)(t^{2}(1 + t))}{1 + t}$

Which Wolfram|Alpha can do no more with than I can, that I gave this method up as a bad job. As far as I can work out, either I'm missing a trick early in the question as far as simplification is concerned - or this method is no good. (Assuming my algebra's alright. I did check, but even if it's not it doesn't look like I'm going to be able to find anything pretty).

So, does MSE have a hint as to how I should better approach this question, or how to simplify my equations?

Edit:

Next I tried the following approach:

Let the area of the triangle = $A_{T}$

$A_{T} = \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix}ct & c/t & 1 \\ -ct & - c/t & 1 \\ ct^{2} & 2ct & 1 \end{vmatrix}$

$A_{T} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(ct\begin{vmatrix}-c/t & 1 \\ 2ct & 1\end{vmatrix} - \dfrac{c}{t}\begin{vmatrix}-ct & 1 \\ ct^{2} & 1\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}-ct & -c/t \\ ct^{2} & 2ct\end{vmatrix}\right)$

$A_{T} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(ct(-c/t - 2ct) - \dfrac{c}{t}(-ct - ct^{2}) + (-2c^{2}t^{2} + c^{2}t)\right)$

$A_{T} = \dfrac{1}{2}(-c^{2} - 2c^{2}t^{2} + c^{2} + c^{2}t^{2} - 2c^{2}t^{2} + c^{2}t)$

$A_{T} = \dfrac{1}{2}(2c^{2}t - 4c^{2}t^{2})$

$A_{T} = c^{2}t(1 - 2t)$

This is very nearly right, but the sign is incorrect and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with linear algebra, the solution is  1/2 the determinant of the matrix $[A-B | C-B]$:

$$A = \frac{1}{2}
\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
ct -(-ct)   & ct^{2}-(-ct) \\
c/t -(-c/t)  & 2ct -(-c/t)  \end{array} \right|
$$
which reduces to $c^2t(2t-1)$.

Comment: Well that is much simpler. I was, once, familiar with matrix algebra and matrices are included in the revision exercise at the beginning of the book so that may be the correct approach to take after all. It's impossible to say for certain, though, as the book I'm using was written before my time so I'm not sure what the students using it would have known and what they wouldn't have. One thing I can say is that no mention of using matrices to calculate areas has yet been made and, like I say, question 7 walks you through the more "naive" method.

Comment: Also you could use Herron's formula which can be used to calculate the area from the length of the three sides.  You can find the formula here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Comment: I wasn't quite able to follow why the solution is 1/2 the determinant of the matrix $[A - B|C - B]$; however, I did look around the internet for assistance in using determinants to calculate the area of a triangle and found this page https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/applications.html. The problem is, the sign is wrong and I don't understand why; can you help? (Question edited to show the approach I tried)

Comment: It is because by subtracting $B$, I effectively translated the triangle to the origin (i.e. point B is now at 0,0).  Then it is known that the area of the parallelogram spanned by $A-B$ and $A-C$ is equal to the determinant shown above.  The area of the triangle is 1/2 the area of the parallelogram, thus the 1/2.

Comment: Regarding the sign, that just depends on the order of the points that you chose to put into the determinant.  If you changed the order from CW to CCW your sign and mine would match.

Comment: The reference that you found is an interesting approach.  It uses the same  principle except it works in 3D space.  The thinking goes like this.  You are constructing your triangle in 3D space by adding $z=1$ as a third coordinate.  So your triangle is floating in space in the horizontal plane $z=1$.  You then compute the volume of the parallelepiped (denote as $V_P = D_3$).  In the same construction you can create a tetrahedron (i.e. pyramid) by connecting your vertices to the origin.  The volume of this is $V_T=1/3(1)A_T$.  It is known that $V_P=6V_T =6(1/3A_T) $, so we get $A_T = 1/2D_3$.